# Bimodules and adjoints

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $A$, $B$ be two algebras over a commutative ring $k$, and let $L$ be a $(B,A)$-bimodule. It is [well-known](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/dualizable-objects-and-morphisms/) that the functor $Mod(A)\rightarrow Mod(B): M\mapsto L\otimes_A M$ has a cocontinuous right adjoint if and only if $L$ is a finitely presented projective right $A$-module. In this case, the right adjoint is the functor $R:Mod(B)\rightarrow Mod(A): N\mapsto Hom_A(L,A)\otimes_B N$. Does the functor $R$ have a cocontinuous right adjoint in general? I.e. is $Hom_A(L,A)$ always a finitely presented projective right $B$-module?

I suspect that this is not true, but have not found any counterexample. This would beg the question: For which $L$ does $R$ have a cocontinuous right adjoint?